# Prove the group of complex points on an elliptic curve is not finitely generated.

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

Recently, in a study of Rational Points on Elliptic Curves, by Silverman and Tate, I went over a proof of Mordell's Theorem. The group of rational points on an elliptic curve is finitely generated. This was proved using the height function.

My question is: How simply can one prove that the group of complex points on an elliptic curve $E(\mathbb{C})$ is not finitely generated?

My proof starts like this:

Assume towards contradiction that the  $E(\mathbb{C})$ is finitely generated.
Then there exists a generating subset of $E(\mathbb{C})$. Denote this subset as $H$. Then my idea is that you can add complex points in the group and get the identity before generating the set, and this is the part that I am having trouble doing.

This is all I have so far... I don't know the best approach at deriving a contradiction.

--

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't know the best approach or you don't know any approach?  I don't see any effort in this question.

Comment: @ErickWong Sorry, about that. Edited.

Comment: Thank you, I have retracted my downvote.

Comment: Finitely generated abelian groups have finite torsion part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finitely generated abelian groups are countable.

Comment: Not just that. Countably generated groups are countable.